# How do I easily append / keep the last 5 lines into some sort of an array

Tags: vb.net

I need to capture the last 5 lines from my "write to log" function so I can add it to a debug email. I can't think of an easy way to do this.

I did think I could have an array with 5 items in it, but I'd still need to shuffle the existing items to add the current data.

Any ideas ?

I'm using vb.net 2005

Comment: Are you familiar with a "queue" data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a queue. if when you add a new item to the queue it exceeds 6, dequeue one item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `List(Of LogEntry)`, the pseudocode is something like this:

1. Append the new LogEntry to the list.
2. While the list has more than five items, remove the item at position 0 (see `RemoveAt`).

This is not space- or CPU-efficient, but it will certainly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> I did think I could have an array with 5 items in it, but I'd still need to shuffle the existing items to add the current data.

Yes, you can shift the array contents to make room for a new items, discarding the oldest item.

Better would be to use a double-linked list, which would allow you to add an item at the start of the list and remove the item from the end of the list (or visa versa) without touching other elements.

In .NET, you want the LinkedList class, then use AddFirst and RemoveLast (or AddLast and RemoveFirst, depending on your needs).

Alternatively, you can use the Queue class (which is probably implemented as a linked list), then call Enqueue and Dequeue.